# Как сделать один класс главнее другова

Tags: html, css

Такой вопрос , работаю с проэктом уже готовым на Bootstrap так вот , там некоторые блоки нужно подредактировать! и мне посоветовали к классам которые уже есть (bootstrap) добавить свой клас и в нем редактировать ! Но проблема в том , что класс bootstrapa всегда перекрывает мой новосозданый клас! Так вот вопрос как сделать мой клас который я создал более главным?

Comment: Разобраться в том, [как вычисляется специфичность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), и сделать такие селекторы, которые перевесят селекторы из бутстрапа

Comment: **!important** можно указать в тех свойствах, которые должны быть главнее. Т.е. в вашем новом классе пишите нужное свойство и добавляете **!important** `.myColor { color: red !important; }`

Comment: @SwaD использовать !important нужно примерно никогда